# Inno Setup installer package supplied file list

Tags: file, inno-setup

I've got a "Project" containing a mixed set of files that my application compiles into an installable using InnoSetup. Many of the project files are system or configuration files, and not relevant to the actual install. Therefore, i want to include only the relevant files in an installer. I have a list of them in my application, but no way to inject this information into the template Inno setup script.

What options are available to achieve this?

Regards

Tris

Note: The files are too big to really be copied in a reasonable length of time. :)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for being so late...and then just asking the obvious: why can't you just keep irrelevant files out of the Inno-Script? Do I understand right: you have an app that generates a setup-script for InnoSetup based on a template? Can't you then modify the app? Alternatively, any chance to edit the ISS and remove the irrelevant files?

Cheers

Michael